# How can I access nested object and render it to datatable?

Tags: reactjs, axios, crud, mern

How can I render the user_id information under the product array? I'm trying to render the nested information of user_id such as the **username**

[image]

[image]

The DataGrid is working successfully since I render all non-nested information or
non-populated info. But I'm also trying to show the information under **user_id**

```
{field: "user_id", headerName: "User Name", width: 250,}
```

this is the field I used, but it's not working since **user_id** is an object

**Edit**
[Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-lamarr-po9cl1?file=/src/App.js)

[image]

This is what I received

Datagrid.js

```
<div className="datatable">
  <DataGrid
    className="datagrid"
    rows={list}
    getRowId={(row) => row._id}
    columns={columns.concat(actionColumn)}
    pageSize={9}
    rowsPerPageOptions={[9]}
    checkboxSelection
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Access it using `user_id.username`

Comment: @Nik it's not working, it just removes the [object Obeject]

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet depicting the problem?

Comment: @Nik Hello sorry for late response, maybe this one will work. 

[Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-lamarr-po9cl1?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you will have to use `renderCell() => ReactElement` property and return the nested object string. I've updated your [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-glitter-yen7gr) with the solution and it is now rendering the username correctly.
Below is the code that I've modified in your code sandbox.

```
{
      field: "user_id",
      headerName: "User Name",
      width: 250,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return params.row.user_id.username;
      },
},
```

[Here](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-definition/#rendering-cells) is the link to documentation that you may want to go through.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this a while ago but it didn't work and crashed, it's the same, I even use Optional chaining. Anyway, thanks for help